# How do I track a message in Exchange 2010 when used as a relay and no mailbox is used?

Tags: email, exchange-2010

We are using Exchange 2010 to relay messages out to the Internet, and there are no local mailboxes, or accepted domains configured.

Mailflow works correctly, and we have a custom routing agent.dll installed.

We need to track a message sent from domain1.com to microsoft.com using SMTP.  Since neither of these domains exist as an accepted domain, how do I track a message with this criteria?

The message tracking website in OWA requires me to select a mailbox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within the `Exchange Management Console` there is an option for `Toolbox`.  In the toolbox is a tool called `Tracking Log Explorer`.  You can use this tool to search for messages at a finer granularity, and without selecting specific mailboxes, but based on email addresses, etc.

Comment: Well, you beat me to it.

Comment: :) I've spent way more time troubleshooting sporadic Exchange issues this month to not be on my toes.

Comment: Remember to enable protocol logging on the relay receive connector and the transport: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124531.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Every message in, out or internal flows through the hub transport server (IIRC) and should be logged by default (IIRC). Use the Tracking Log Explorer to look for the message.

Select the Recipient checkbox and type the email address of the recipient (someguy@microsoft.com).

Select the Server checkbox and type the name of your hub transport server.

Uncheck the EventID check box (to see all events related to the message).

Select the appropriate date/time range.

Click Next.

Look at the results to determine the disposition of the message and to track it further.

Answer (score 3):

```
X:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\TransportRoles\Logs\MessageTracking
```

They're CSVs too, so filtering and searching them with Powershell is a breeze.

[image]